# Adding custom column into configurable product grid in admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have created a custom column for associated products (basically every simple product will have that column under "associated products" tab of configurable product). I store information of this field/column into an attribute which belong to configurable product instead of each simple product.

Below is the code for adding a column;

**config.xml**

```
<core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
     <observers>
        <something>
          <class>namespace_JsonProductInfo_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>addPositionColumn</method>
        </something>
     </observers>
</core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
```

**Oberver.php**

```
public function addPositionColumn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Grid) {
            if (!$block->isReadonly()) {
                $block->addColumnAfter(
                    'position_simple',
                    array(
                        'header'     => Mage::helper('jsonproductinfo')->__('Position'),
                        'type'      => 'input',
                        'name'      => 'position_simple',
                        'index'     => 'position_simple',
                        'sortable'  => false,
                    ),
                    'name'
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

With above code I am able to add the column into a require grid. And I am also able to save the information which I put inside that column (which is basically an attribute). The only problem I am facing is, I am unable to display the stored information into that column again (If I edit the product). I have also created another observer of type **eav_collection_abstract_load_befor** but no luck so far.
Below is the code for it:

**config.xml**

```
<eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
  <observers>
    <jsonproductinfo>
      <class>namespace_JsonProductInfo_Model_Observer</class>
      <method>addPositionToCatalogProductCollection</method>
    </jsonproductinfo>
  </observers>
</eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
```

**Observer.php**

```
public function addPositionToCatalogProductCollection($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        if (!isset($collection)) {
            return;
        }
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('position_simple');
    }
```

I would be grateful if someone can point to the mistake or guide me how can I display back that information again into that column.

> **EDIT** And here is the code which creates the "position_simple" attribute.

```
$this->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'position_simple',
    array(
        'group'             => 'General',
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'input'             => 'hidden',
        'backend'           => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'label'             => 'Simple Position',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => '',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'           => true,
        'required'          => false,
        'user_defined'      => true,
        'default'           => '',
        'searchable'        => false,
        'filterable'        => false,
        'comparable'        => false,
        'visible_on_front'   => false,
        'visible_in_advanced_search'   => false,
        'unique'            => false,
        'apply_to'          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE,
        'is_configurable'   => false,
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. change `'index' => 'position_simple'` to `'index' => 'entity_id'` in your **Observer.php** (function addPositionColumn)
2. you need to get value of your `position_simple` attribute from configurable product and use it in added column - one way to do that:

create function in **Observer.php**

```
protected function _getDefaultConfigurationId() {
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if ($product) {
        return array($product->getData('position_simple'));
    }
    return '';
}
```

and use that in your addPositionColumn function like that:

```
...    
'values' => $this->_getDefaultConfigurationId(),
...
```

After that, there is no need of observer type **eav_collection_abstract_load_befor** at all.